# How to create Postgres backups from docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a **Postgres 9.5.4** database running inside a docker container. I am using the [official Postgres images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) and I have been trying to create backups from my database, but not luck so far. According [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) I was expecting the following command to store the **dump.tar** file in the **/releases/** folder in the host machine (outside the temporal docker container)

```bash
  docker run -i --rm --link my_postgres:postgres --volume /releases/:/tmp/ postgres:latest pg_dumpall > /tmp/dump.tar
```

But this throws the following error:

```
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: how did u create your postgres container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have found the solution

```bash
docker run -i --rm --link my_container:postgres -v /releases/:/tmp/ postgres:latest bash -c 'exec pg_dumpall -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U postgres  > /tmp/my_backup.tar'
```

Where Docker arguments:

- **-i** For interactive processes, like a shell, bash, etc.
- **--rm** For deleting the container once the backup is finished
- **--link** For linking this temporal container to **my_container**, which contains the currently running Postgres database.
- **-v /releases/:/tmp/** Creates shared volume. The content inside the folder **/tmp/** in the container (In this case **my_backup.tar**) will be automatically visible on folder **/releases/** in the host machine.

And bash arguments:

- **pg_dumpall** To export PostgreSQL cluster into a script file.
- **-h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR"** Obtains the ip address out of the Postgres variable.
- **-p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT"** Obtains the Port out of the Postgres variable (These variables are defined only in the temporal container we just created, as result of the linkage with **my_container**)
- **-U** The username for connecting to the database